# Difference between dehnen and strecken

Tags: meaning

While researching the difference in meaning between dehnen und strecken I came across this:

> Die Zeit, 13.08.2003, Nr. 33> Im Halbschlaf **strecke** ich und **dehne** meine müde gewanderten Beine.

How is this sentence not redundant?

I further note that DWDS under stecken supplies this example:

> sich, die Glieder so lang wie möglich dehnen, recken
>
> > Beispiele:
> >
> > > er reckte und streckte sich, **streckte** und **dehnte** die Glieder

also appearing redundant.

Comment: To see the difference, think of a standing quad stretch: The leg is bent, i.e. not extended, but the quadriceps muscle is stretched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the two terms are often used together, the underlying meaning is different,

*Strecken* implies a direction, often (but not necessarily) towards a goal or target. It’s stretch in the sense of straightening out or reaching for something. It can be used literally (die Beine strecken - to straighten one’s legs) or figuratively ([*sich nach der Decke strecken*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/sich%20nach%20der%20Decke%20strecken) - meaning to use limited available means to get by; *etwas (e.g. drugs, soup) strecken* - to mix in something cheaper to make a supply last longer)

*Dehnen* means widen or loosen something that was previously (too) tight. It implies a purpose.

This difference explains why both terms can be used in a seemingly overlapping sense:

In your first example, the person straightened their legs with the purpose of loosening them (technically the muscles and ligaments in the legs, but that’s medical nitpicking and the German language is perfectly fine with this bit on imprecision).
The same explanation is valid for the second example.

Comment: So, why can one, die Beine ausstrecken, but not, die Beine ausdehnen, if one can, die Beine strecken und dehnen?

Comment: Because you can stretch your legs in a direction (ausstrecken by straightening the joints), but ultimately not make them (semi-)permanently longer/wider (except for some medical issues). Ausdehnung often implies two or three dimensions, expansion.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not so much redundant as unprecise. One can "seine Beine strecken" (*stretch [out] ones legs*) but "die Beine dehnen" (in English also "stretch", but in the sense of "to lengthen") should be a very painful (and ultimately futile) act. What you can "dehnen" are not legs but muscles and ligaments. These can shorten and/or tend to cramp from hard usage. This is implied by "müde gewandert" which translates to "hiked to tiredness".

It is difficult to say lacking more context, but i suppose what the author wanted to say was he "streckte *sich*" (not his legs). This is a set phrase and means to uncurl, to have a stretch. This activity includes the legs, but is not confined to these and involves the whole body.

Comment: Sorry, but this example given in DWDS under strecken would not seem to confirm what you are saying: "streckte und dehnte die Glieder". I am appending the question.

Comment: I do not see how the sentence is imprecise, unless you consider all instances of metonymy such: *He broke his arm, they drank another glass, Berlin vetoed the proposal*.